# Is there any nonlinear LQR controller?

Tags: optimization, dynamical-systems, control-theory, optimal-control, kalman-filter

There is a nonlinear LQE observer. It's more referred as Extended Kalman Filter(EKF). It's quite easy, just linearize matrix $A$ and $C$ in the estimated vector $\hat{x}$ before you find the kalman gain matrix $K$ from the Riccati equation.

But is ther a nonlinear LQR controller?

Can I just linearize matrix $A$ and $B$ in the estimated vector $\hat{x}$ before I find the control law gain matrix $L$ from the Riccati equation? But still have the same $Q$ and $R$ weighting matrices?

Comment: There are a few different variations I guess. I would suggest starting with looking at iLQG or tvLQR.

Comment: Cannot find anything about tvLQR. But iLQG looks interesting. It's a nonlinear LQR ?

Comment: **tvLQR** is "time-varying LQR", see [this application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QREeZvHg0lQ) and [this reference](http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/underactuated.html?chapter=10) (10.2.2).    
    
**iLQG** is "iterated LQG", where you are basically following along a nominal trajectory, and applying LQG along that trajectory by linearizing as you go. Of course if your controller causes you to deviate, your linearization is no longer accurate, so you iterate along the new nominal trajectory, re-linearizing.

Comment: What would happen if I linearize  $f(x,u) $ in the estimated state vector to update the control lag  $L $ ?

Comment: I think model predictive control would be a general extension of LQR. However finding the global minimal solution in general might be hard, because the nonlinearities can make the problem non-convex.

Comment: Okej. So MPC just more like a better version that LQR? Is MPC robust control, optimal control or only nonlinear  control ? Can I apply EKF with MPC ?

Comment: Not to be annoying or cheeky but since it says in the name that it's a Linear Quadratic Regulator, it would be strange to ask for a nonlinear linear quadratic regulator. The assumptions are hammered into its derivation, that is why people linearize before they implement the LQR. Maybe you are looking for dedicated nonlinear controllers?

Comment: @mr.fegur  yes. I'm trying to learn robust control now.